# How can I combine multiple regular expression conditions in a single awk command?

Tags: bash, awk

Type the shell command, which says how many times it has a whitespace in a particular file, and that it consists of at least four numbers (for example: "" 1945 "").
When I tried to solve the above exercise, I could not reach the result that I wanted, I want your help in this subject.
First of all, I created a txt file and filled it with random numbers. - sign represents spaces.

```
---234352432- 
-123---
-12342---
-1-
-12345-
122333
```

I made a code to find the count of the numbers with more than 4 digits and has spaces in front of and behind of numbers.

```
cat text1.txt | awk '/^[[:space:]]&&[0-9]{4,}&&[[:space:]]$/' | awk 'END {print NR}'
```

returned 0

```
cat text1.txt | awk '/^" "/' | awk '/[0-9] {4, }/' | awk '/" "$/' | awk '{print NR}'
```

returned 6

Comment: `&&` inside `/something&&something else/` match _literal_ `&` characters. I guess you meant `/something/ && /something else/`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if($i ~ /^[0-9]/&&$i>999) {print $i}}}' text1.txt >> text2.txt | awk 'END {print NR}' text2.txt
```

That worked on my case. Thank u for everything

Comment: That doesn't do what you asked for and the `|` doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

To match a line that starts with white space then has 4 or more contiguous digits then white space to the end of the line:

```
$ awk '/^[[:space:]]+[0-9]{4,}[[:space:]]+$/{c++} END{print c+0}' file
3
```

To match a line that starts with white space, ends with white space and contains 4 or more contiguous digits somewhere on the line:

```
$ awk '/^[[:space:]]+/ && /[0-9]{4,}/ && /[[:space:]]+$/{c++} END{print c+0}' file
3
```

They'll behave the same with the input you provided but try them both with:

```
    3 foo 12345 bar 7
```

for example (where that line has blanks at the start and end).

You never need to `cat` a file into a pipe to awk (or any other command), nor do you need a pipeline of multiple awk commands (nor pipes of awk+sed+grep, etc.) so if you ever find yourself doing any of that know you're using the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

this might be easier with `grep`

```
$ grep -Ec '\s[0-9]{4,}\s' file
3
```

to verify the matches

```
$ grep -E '\s[0-9]{4,}\s' file | tr ' ' '-'
---234352432--
-12342---
-12345-
```

Comment: ITYM **GNU** grep (for `\s`).

Comment: Yes, right GNU.  Not sure why it's not a standard?  Char classes feel too verbose.

Comment: Probably backwards-compatibility with existing scripts that consider `\s` literal. It'd be tough to argue for breaking backwards compatibility in a standards release over something that just saves a few characters typing.